# Explicit constructor call in C++

Tags: c++

1) what is the return value of following statement:

```
obj.classX::classX();
```

2) Another question regarding constructors in C++:

```
 classX();
```

creates an object. What is the expanded code generated by the compiler?

Comment: First statement is illegal, you cannot call a constructor. Don't do it. And there is no "standard compiler", so what code gets generated by a compiler depends totally on the compiler. Generally, whatever code is needed to invoke the constructor and then the destructor.

Answer (score 4):

Constructors do not return a value. Just like a function returning `void`.

for your 2nd question, the compiler will call the constructor, then the destructor.

Comment: i tried printing the value of mVarX using following statement:
(obj.classX::classX();).mVarX
& it is printing correct value!
I am not able to understand this behavior.

Comment: This temp variable will go out of scope at the ;

Answer (score 3):

1. It doesn't have a return value. Therefore, it would be treated as `void`. You can't actually call the constructor that way though, so it matters little.
2. That's compiler dependent of course, but in general it will allocate memory on the stack, and call the constructor to construct the object on the stack. Then the destructor will be called and the memory will be returned to the stack.

Comment: 1) Do u mean obj.classX::classX(); is not valid?

 I tried this statement & Its calling constructor.

Comment: What do you mean its compiler dependent. Looks well defined to me.

Comment: @Martin York: The standard says very little about where things are actually stored. You could implement C++ on a platform that did not have any sort of hardware stack. It specifies only that the object would be constructed in the same place other automatic variables would be constructed. Exactly where that is, however, is not defined by the standard.

Comment: @Billy ONeal:  What the standard does say is that an object will be created. This means the constructor will be called and the destructor will be called.

Comment: @Billy @Marin: I think the confusion is the way you're interpreting the question: "What is the expanded code generated by compiler?" Billy is focused on the 'code generation' part, which is obviously compiler dependant, while Martin is focusing on the 'what will happen' part, which is different from 'how' and compiler independant. I think Billy's approach is more "correct" per se, but both directions can be implied by the question.

Comment: @Martin York: Yes, that is correct. An object will be created and then destroyed -- that is well defined. The compiler/machine dependent part is from where the memory for that object is obtained. For 99% of machines, that will be the hardware stack, but it does not *have* to be.

Comment: @theneuronarc: Sorry, I missed that comment somehow. Yes, what I mean is that the first statement you posted is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.classX::classX();
```

This is compile time error.

```
classX();
```

This creates a temporary instance of `classX` that is destroyed right at the end of the statement, IOW at the semicolon.

Comment: obj.classX::classX(); 

is not giving me any compilation errors and its calling constructor.

I am using MSVS2005.

Comment: @theneuronarc: So VC8 compiles this. And what's your point? That VC isn't the most standard conforming compiler around? We knew that. `:)`

Comment: @theneuronarc: Nevertheless it is not valid C++. Try the same on codepad.org (e.g. http://codepad.org/T9zkz2Dn) or with Comeau (http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/). It will not compile.

Comment: @theneuronarc: Compilers don't determine the language, the standard does. You cannot call the constructor, period. You may use placement-new which will construct an object a location, though.